# Can I substitute the object, which is currently being dragged in React-Konva?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, resize, react-konva

What I need is a way to somehow substitute an object in react-konva. When ondrag() is fired on an object, I want to instead create its clone on a different layer and force the user into dragging it instead of the original one.

This transition should not be noticeable by the user. The original object will be hidden after this happens, but that is not the problem. I would also like to find a way to do the same while resizing the stage object.